# OpenGL inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, opengl, jframe, awt

I want to make an application which will have the following:
a jframe (or frame, or whatever) with some java style menus (Jmenu) on the side, and on the other side of the jframe, a OpenGL canvas (which only occupies part of the jframe) and let them integrate together.
meaning, for example, I want to change a slide, and it will change the view of the opengl.

Is it even possible to embed an OpenGL inside a Jframe?

Also, a recomandation for an opengl library that would support such thing. I played a bit with JOGL, but also saw that there are other open-source, and also LWGL and stuff

EDIT:
Added an image from a project made with JOGL which is exactly what I'm after.
A canvas of JOGL inside a Java GUI
[image]

Comment: [Using JOGL in AWT SWT and Swing](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_AWT_SWT_and_Swing)

Comment: thanks, it looks like the way to go, however i can't figure out how to add the controls (like in the picture) and to change the size of the opengl thingy to not take the whole screen, it seems to only accept one of the two. which ever I add later to the jframe

Comment: Well, just like you do `frame.add(glCanvas);` you can add other AWT (or whatever) components. Google some AWT/SWT/Swing tutorial to get started; I'd personally recommend SWT.

Comment: That's what i did. but it only shows the last one I added (either all the components, or the opengl

Comment: Do something like: `frame.add(new Button("OK"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);` and read up on layouts etc. in AWT...

Comment: in now shows, but I still don't know how to resize the opengl component.
thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

- for hight Graphics performance is required to use AWT Component exclusively,
- I'd suggesting not [mixing AWT with Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/)
- [maybe JOGL could be right way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL), maybe not

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but i'm not sure what you mean.
I have no problem using only AWT, I'm interested in mixing ANY available java window with an OpenGL thingy

Comment: 1) for printscreen use white backgroung, 2) `I'm interested in mixing ANY available java` == you can to try that, but I'm for plain AWT, 3) in all Swing APIs are inheriths from AWT, then AWT container with Swing JComponent if required, 4) if you'll look aroung, mediaplayer, 3D emulators are based on containers like as from ZOO or Circus, becasue I think low level programing languages have got poor accesses to the todays GUI frameworks